# IE double printing issue

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, printing-web-page

Ok...this is extremely weird.

I have a form that's being printed by my client and in Firefox it's great!  In chrome it's great!  In IE...it prints the questions twice.  From 13 to 26 pages.

I can't figure it out
http://intranet.barberitos.com/compliance_new/index.php?Form_ID=1&store_address=16

ANY IDEAS would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure your form isn't splist across two divs. this can cause printing issues in IE7.

Comment: GOOD LORD!!  That's it!!  Dude, you're a life saver.